# Passing parrallel array from file

Tags: java, arrays

Directions are to pass data from a file into an array for studentName and studentGrade.
he text file looks like this:

```
Sandy 94 91 93 91 99 93 97 93
Randy 90 89 100 100 92 89 92 99
Randi 88 98 89 100 100 81 91 91
Mandy 82 84 99 88 98 85 95 85
Mandie 84 96 88 91 82 75 83 92
Mandi 80 84 95 83 73 82 97 89
Andy 77 98 84 70 80 70 72 94
Brandy 90 86 82 70 95 85 91 80
Brandi 78 67 79 95 92 68 98 81
Candie 89 97 72 85 60 72 94 95
```

There are 2 methods that I don't understand how to pass:

getStudentNameByIndex – a method that takes an integer as an argument which is used as an index
into the names array and returns the name at that index.

getGradeByIndex – a method that takes an integer as an argument which is used as an index into thestudentGrades array and returns the grade at that index.

```
public class Main {

    public static final int MAX_STUDENT = 50;
    public static final String FILE_PATH = "grade1.txt";
    public static final String MENU_QUIT = "Quit";
    public static final String HIGHEST_GRADE = "Highest Grade";
    public static final String LOWEST_GRADE = "Lowest Grade";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Option = " ";
        char menuSelection = ' ';
        double grade = 0;
    
        ClassRoom sg = new ClassRoom();
        sg.loadGrades(FILE_PATH);
        System.out.println(sg.findMaxGradeIndex());
        System.out.println(sg.findMinGradeIndex());
    
        /*
         * displayWelcome(); displayMenu();
         * 
         * 
         * menuSelection = getValidatedSelection(input);
         * 
         * while (menuSelection != 'Q') {
         * 
         * while (menuSelection == 'A') { Option = HIGHEST_GRADE;
         * 
         * System.out.printf("%.2f", grade);
         * 
         * }{ Option = LOWEST_GRADE; grade = sg.findMinGradeIndex();
         * 
         * }//end of else displaySelecetion(grade); }//end of loop
         * 
         * displayFarewell();
         */
    }// end of main
    
    private static void displaySelecetion(double grade) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f", grade);
    
    }
    
    private static void displayFarewell() {
        System.out.println("End of Grading Program");
    
    }
    
    private static char getValidatedSelection(Scanner input) {
        char selection;
    
        selection = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        // validate selection
        while (selection != 'A' && selection != 'B' && selection != 'Q') {
            System.out.println("Invailid Selection.\n");
    
            displayMenu();
            selection = input.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        }
    
        return selection;
    }
    
    private static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("Display Menu:");
        System.out.printf("%-4s%-10s\n", "(A)", HIGHEST_GRADE);
        System.out.printf("%-4s%-10s\n", "(B)", LOWEST_GRADE);
        System.out.printf("%-4s%-10s\n", "(Q)", MENU_QUIT);
        System.out.println("Please Make A Selection");
    
    }
    
    private static void displayWelcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Grading Program:");
    
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ClassRoom {

    private String courseName;
    private String[] studentNames = new String[50];
    private double[] studentGrades = new double[50];
    private int numStudents = 10;
    
    public void loadGrades(String file) {
        try {
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
            double sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            courseName = readFile.next();
    
            while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
                studentNames[count] = readFile.next();
                double grade1 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double grade2 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double grade3 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double grade4 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double grade5 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double grade6 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double grade7 = readFile.nextDouble();
                double finalGrade = readFile.nextDouble();
                sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5 + grade6 + grade7 + 3 * finalGrade;
                sum = sum / 10;
                studentGrades[count] = sum;
                count++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }
    
    public int findMaxGradeIndex() {
        double highest = 0;
        for (int index = 1; index < studentGrades.length; index++) {
            if (studentGrades[index] > highest)
                highest = studentGrades[index];
    
        }
        return (int) highest;
    }
    
    public int findMinGradeIndex() {
        double lowest = studentGrades[0];
        for (int index = 1; index < 8; index++) {
            if (studentGrades[index] < lowest)
                lowest = studentGrades[index];
        }
        return (int) lowest;
    }
    
    public String getStudentNameByIndex(int name) {
        int integer = 0;
    
        return studentNames[name];
    }
    
    public double getGradeByIndex(int grade) {
        return studentGrades[grade];
    }
    
    public int getnumStudents() {
        return numStudents;
    }

}
```

Comment: Parallel arrays should be avoided. Make a `Student` class and keep the grades as a member of that

Comment: I don't understand how to make a method return as an index and call that method in the main class, without errors.

Comment: I was able to run the code, it works well, it only requires a few minor adjustments.  What is the specific error, or errors, encountered, when trying to use the _getStudentNameByIndex_ and _getGradeByIndex_ methods?

Comment: You've already implemented those methods. There's nothing wrong other than bad naming (the parameter is an *index*, not a name/grade)

Comment: I'm so sorry for not explaining well, I am trying my best to understand Java. But the point I am trying to get at is:
findMaxGradeIndex – a method that returns the index of the maximum total grade. It does not need 
any arguments.
findMinGradeIndex – a method that returns the index of the minimum total grade. It does not need 
any argument
How would I pass getStudentNamebyIndex and getGradeByIndex from the methods findMaxGradeIndex and findMinGradeIndex?
I have to pass findMin/MaxGradeIndex into getStudentNameByIndex and getGradeByIndex

Answer (score 0):

> *"... How would I pass getStudentNamebyIndex and getGradeByIndex from the methods findMaxGradeIndex and findMinGradeIndex? ..."*

First, you'll need to change the return value of *findMaxGradeIndex* and *findMinGradeIndex*, as they are returning the grade, and not the index.

I introduced a new variable, *indexOf* and assigned it during the *studentGrades* access.
And, subsequently changed the return value to *indexOf*.

```java
public int findMaxGradeIndex() {
    double highest = 0;
    int indexOf = 0;
    for (int index = 1; index < studentGrades.length; index++) {
        if (studentGrades[index] > highest)
            highest = studentGrades[indexOf = index];
    }
    return indexOf;
}
```

Same situation for *findMinGradeIndex*.

```java
public int findMinGradeIndex() {
    double lowest = studentGrades[0];
    int indexOf = 0;
    for (int index = 1; index < 8; index++) {
        if (studentGrades[index] < lowest)
            lowest = studentGrades[indexOf = index];
    }
    return indexOf;
}
```

From here, you can use the output of these methods, as input for the *getStudentNameByIndex*, and *getGradeByIndex*, methods.

```java
System.out.println(sg.getStudentNameByIndex(sg.findMaxGradeIndex()));
System.out.println(sg.getStudentNameByIndex(sg.findMinGradeIndex()));
```

Output

```
Randy
Andy
```

As for the *getGradeByIndex* method, I am unsure of what is expected from it.
If you could provide some additional information, I'd be glad to include an additional recommendation.

On a final note, there are a few errors in the code that I might as well mention.

In the *loadGrades* method, I have to comment-out the following line.
It was throwing off the input read by the *readFile* *Scanner*.

```java
courseName = readFile.next();
```

For *sum*, you are dividing by *10*, and there are only *9* values.

```java
sum = sum / 10;
```

And, the *findMaxGradeIndex* *for-loop* is skipping over index *0*, since *index* starts at *1*.

```java
for (int index = 1; index < studentGrades.length; index++)
```

Overall, this is a good approach, it functions correctly.
Some additional improvements would be to utilize a *[collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html)*, rather than an *array*.
The size is dynamic, and will adjust as you add values.